# SQL: WHERE field LIKE LEFT(x, x)%

Tags: sql

Quick question.
I need to look for the records where the first 7 digits of a field matches my condition. Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE LEFT(condition, 7)%
```

So that, when condition = 1000000000
Field value

1000000000 will match

1000000010 will match

1000000100 will match

1000001000 will not match

Hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance.

Comment: how does the `field` look like? you can `cast()` the `field` in the `where` condition and use `left()` as a string.

Comment: @samkart, Thanks for taking the time to answer. field is a string, but part of the index, and the table contains quite a lot of records. So I cant do WHERE LEFT(field, 7) = LEFT(condition, 7), as this would slow the execution down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out, its easy. SQL is not my strong suit :-) So this seems to work fine

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(condition, 7), %)
```

Have a nice day